# Strings and Ints in C++

Tags: c++

First off, this is for a homework assignment, so I'd appreciate help and guidance rather than just the answer in code.

The purpose of the code should be for a user to input a number and a width.

If the width is longer than the number, the number will be printed out with zeros in front of the number. For example `43 3` would give `043`.

If the width isn't longer just the number would be printed: `433 2` would be `433`.

I think I have to get the count of characters in the number and compare it to the count of characters in the width (`if-else` statement).

Then, if the number of characters in the number is more, print out the number. Else, print out the width.

I think I get the number of zeros by subtracting the length of the number from the length of the width.  Then use that to set the number of zeros.  Like I said this is homework and would rather learn than be given the answer.

If anyone can help, it'll be appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>;
    #include <string>;

    using namespace std;

    string format(int number, int width) {


    int count = 0;
      if (number > width)// This if-else is incomplete
          return ;  
      else              

    }

    int main() 
    {
     cout << "Enter a number: ";
     string n;
     cin >> n;

     cout << "Enter the number's width: ";
     string w;
     cin >> w;

     format(n, w);

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: use `atoi()` to convert `n.c_str()` to an `int`

Comment: Sorry, really frustrated and forgot the questions.  Is my thinking right and how do you get the ints to work into the string function.

Comment: The *code* is formatted okay, it's just the morass of English text that's hard to read :-) Let's see what we can do about that ...

Comment: We haven't learned about atoi yet.  I saw that in my GOOGLE journey, though.  The professor wants use to use what we learned so far(basic beginner stuff) like size() and length().

Comment: @self `atoi` is rarely a good solution.

Comment: Then I'd suggest reading the numbers into ints instead of strings.

Comment: @Derek lol. use `strtod` then, -- or roll your own which is a horrible idea. This is C land, these are functions available from the standard library

Comment: @self How would we use `strtod` with integers? I'd suggest using `stringstream` instead of `atoi`. The question is tagged as C++, so this is not "C land".

Answer (score 0):

no need to checking string or other things write these code C++ will do it for you automatically.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

#include <string>;
using std::string;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

void format(int number, int width)
{
    cout.fill('0');

    cout << setw(width) << number;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Enter the number's width: ";
    int w;
    cin >> w;

    format(n, w);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't using strings, so why `#include <string>`? and what happens when I enter text instead of a number? Also, `conio.h` is not a standard C++ header.

Comment: excuse me i just copied code and edited it, and what you mean I entered and string when you talking about number and width it must be an integer.

Comment: Thank you first off, so you're filling in the width with zeros where there's no digits?  That seems so much simpler.

Comment: and by the way I used conio.h just because of _getch(), but you can press ctrl + F5 instead of using _getch().

Comment: You could also use `std::cin.ignore();` and not use `conio.h`.

Comment: yes it fills 0 instead of spaces and then set's the width with setw(width).